# Retaining column ordering in jqGrid across session

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net

I have a jqGrid in my asp.net (C#) application and I can reorder the columns in this grid.
Suppose the current order of columns (Emp ID, Emp Name, Designation) is 1,2,3 and I change it to 1,3,2. Now I navigate to some other page and returns to this page again. I want my reordering preference to retain, i.e., 1,3,2.
Is there any property with jqGrid that captures the order of column in the grid?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Arpit

Answer (score 0):

There is an API in jqGrid for configuration import/export:

- http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:import_methods

You can find some samples (for ASP.NET MVC) here:

- http://tpeczek.com/2010/01/jqgrid-and-aspnet-mvc-configuration.html
- http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/61796